Characters truncated in named credentials custom header parameter
ConnectApi.ExternalCredential externalCred = ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.getExternalCredential('SN_JWT');
System.debug('externalCred :'+externalCred);
when I run this code in salesforce ... in system.debug I can see only 1000 characters of a parameter which is sent as custom header in named credentials in salesforce. checked raw logs and apex debug logs also still can see only 1000 characters. what is reason of this whereas am passing 4500 characters in cert custom header in named credentials and referencing it in apex. Not getting any authentication failure/ error but want to know reason. Is this behaviour with system.debug or behaviour of ConnectApi.ExternalCredential externalCred = ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.getExternalCredential or a probable bug in apex. Please guide.

I suggest to make clear in the question it refers to the headerValue of ConnectApi.CredentialCustomHeader.
